# Retain the session value when browser is opened for the second time

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

First time login to the asp.net application,stored some session value

```
  Eg: Session["Test"]="Saving Sesison";
```

Logout the application

When opened the browser for the second time,need to retain the same session value.

```
  Eg: Session["Test"]="Saving Sesison";
```

How can i do that,can anyone help me with some solution to proceed further please.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  if (Session["Test"] == null)      
                {
                    Binding data to repeater control(with out filter)
                }
                else
                {
                    //Get Session value (To maintain session value across the browser)
                    var cookieSession = Request.Cookies["Test"];      //While opening   the browser for the 2nd time,this line is getting null for all the browsers,but session is getting value for firefox & Chrome not for IE { Session["Test"] }
                if (cookieSession != null &&!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieSession.Value))
                    {
                        Session["Test"] = cookieSession.Value;
                    }
                    Binding data to repeater control(with filter using session value)
                }
```

}

```
//On Drop down selection.

protected void Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Binding data to repeater control(based on the dropdown selected value)

Session["Test"] = Dropdown.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(); //To maintain the Dropdown selection all over the app
       // Set it
       if (Session["Test"] == null)
       {
           Session["Test"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
           var cookie = new HttpCookie("Test", (string)Session["Test"]);
           Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Session scope is for only particular session only. So its not possible to have that kind of functionality.

But you can use Cache in same way and it will be there until you make it null or time period exceeds.  But beware of fact that it will be there for every browser. So either you need to use different key(Unique key) not like 'test'

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Though sessions should be sticky between a browser being re-launched assuming it's not in private/incognito mode. If you're finding the session is timing out too quickly you can extend it in Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="10080" mode="InProc" />
</system.web>
```

Where `timeout` is in minutes.  Note: If you're are debugging stopping and starting the debugger will reset your sessions. So will any kind of re-deployment of the application on IIS. If this is an issue for you, you should check out using something like the SQL session state provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx

Another method of dealing with this is to store some kind of token in a cookie (again, only works if the browser is not in incognito/private mode, and the user data hasn't been flushed).

```
// Set it
if (Session["Test"] == null)    
{
    Session["Test"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();     
   
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("Test", (string)Session["Test"]);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}


// Get it
var cookieSession = Request.Cookies["Test"];

if (cookieSession != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieSession.Value))
{
    Session["Test"] = cookieSession.Value;
}
```

As a note using the SQL session state provider while is one of the more persistent storages there can be some serious overhead requirements. It's easy to rack up a couple of gigs worth of sessions that are being tracked.

In my experience a combination of cookies and the session provider seem to work best if you need to be very certain that some things are sticking to a users experience on the site.

### Edit

So the issue with your drop down selection saver is it's always false and should never set the cookie.

```
protected void Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Binding data to repeater control(based on the dropdown selected value)

    // add to Session
    Session["Test"] = Dropdown.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(); 
    
    // Add Cookie
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("Test", (string)Session["Test"]);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Now to get your data back out, put this code in the actions/controllers to run BEFORE you try to access `Session["Test"]`

```
var cookieSession = Request.Cookies["Test"];

if (cookieSession != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieSession.Value))
{
    Session["Test"] = cookieSession.Value; // Should contain the selected text from the drop down
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,will try your solution

Comment: this is working in firefox & Chrome but not in IE.Can you plz help me to work it on IE also.Business clients will use IE most of the time.

Comment: Very strange it doesn't work in IE, this isn't using anything that browser's haven't supported since the beginning of the internet. Which part isn't working, both the session and the cookie? If it's both can you check in IE dev tools if it's setting the cookies in the response from the site?

Comment: At any point in your code anywhere are you calling `Session.Abandon();` or `Session.Clear();` or something similar to those?

Comment: No,am not clearing any sessions and cookies.Both are not working.That's what am confused like how come,its working in firefox & chrome but not in IE.(am using IE 8)

Comment: In the developer tools are you seeing the cookie being passed back to the browser?

Comment: I have updated the question,Please have a look and provide some solution. @ Siva

Comment: @user1676709 I updated my answer. I think the issue was you were never actually setting the cookie because you assigned to `Session["Test"]` and then checked for `null` which would always be false.